# How can I download all svn revision?

Tags: svn, download, revision

I m using tortoise svn as client server. I can download any specific revision of any svn repository. But i need to download all revisions of a svn repository together. How can I do that?

Comment: Read this first https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.tour . There is no need to donwload all revision when you can revert to any revision at any time

Comment: But I need full revisions of a repository together for my research work. Thank you.